# okay to use 男／女 as opposed to 男／女の人 to refer to yourself?

Tags: word-choice, politeness

A friend of mine is practicing Japanese and created the sentence 私は女の人ではありません。私も男の人ではありません intending to say "I am not a woman, I am also not a man"

I offered to improve the sentence as 私は男でも女でもありません, still a little stiff but sounds more natural at least to my ears. Which got me wondering. I know that you should not use plain 男／女 to refer to others because that is rude, [which this question talks about](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4380/when-should-%E7%94%B7%E3%81%AE%E4%BA%BA-%E5%A5%B3%E3%81%AE%E4%BA%BA-be-used-instead-of-%E7%94%B7-%E5%A5%B3), but what about using them to refer to yourself, is that fine? Does that sound more natural than using の人?

Furthermore, if I were talking about someone else, and I said 僕の友人は男の人でも女の人でもありません does that sound reasonably natural (albeit stiff). Furthermore does 僕の友人は男でも女の人でもありません flow better, or is it just unnatural or ungrammatical?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

私は男でも女でもありません is perfectly fine.

- When you refer to yourself, you don't have to add の人.
- Even when you refer to someone else, 男/女 tends to sound safe when used predicatively, because you are clearly focusing on one's gender in such a case. It is literary or rude when used as a simple noun (as a subject, object, etc):

  > - あの人は男です。: fine
  >     <sub>(男性/女性です is better if you need to speak politely)</sub>
  > - 昨日見た女: literary/rude
  > - あそこにいる男と話そう。: literary/rude

Comment: Can 男／女の人 be used predicatively? Like 「私は女の人です」 or 「会長は男の人です」. Or does it sound weird?

Comment: @E.Matsunaga 私は女の人です sounds weird because you are using の人 to yourself. 会長は男の人です is fine.

Comment: That was exactly my doubt. Somehow using 「の人」 with myself sounded weird even to me.